# Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react'

Tags: reactjs

I want to install [neumorphism-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neumorphism-react) package.

But I got this error

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in
> 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\react
> projects\visitor\node_modules@emotion\styled\base\dist'

Here are the dependencies in `package.json`

```
"@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
"neumorphism-react": "^1.1.1",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
"semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
```

Comment: Looks like you're needing the `@emotion/react` package, it's no in your dependency and obviously not being included in your dependencies' dependencies either

Answer (score 162):

I had a similar issue and I resolved it by calling:

```
npm install @emotion/react
```

or

```
yarn add @emotion/react
```

Comment: After installing the package a restart of npm might be needed. Just stop the server and run `npm start`.

Comment: after this error i got Can´t resolve @emotion/styled

Comment: This plus restarting the app server worked.

Comment: Make sure that you add ALL necessary packages. In my case it was `@emotion/utils` `@emotion/cache` `@emotion/serialize`.

Answer (score 137):

I had a similar issue and I resolved it by calling:

```
npm install @emotion/react 
npm install @emotion/styled
```

or

```
 yarn add @emotion/react
 yarn add @emotion/styled
```

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue and I resolved it by calling:

for the npm:

```
npm install @emotion/react 
npm install @emotion/styled
```

for the yarn:

```
yarn add @emotion/react
yarn add @emotion/styled
```

For specific version you can install like : `@emotion/core@10.1.1`   & `@emotion/styled`

in npm:

```
npm install @emotion/core@10.1.1
npm install @emotion/styled
```

in yarn:

```
yarn add @emotion/core@10.1.1
yarn add @emotion/styled
```

Answer (score 17):

An all-stop solution...

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Answer (score 16):

For those who are using nextJS, try to delete the .next dir after installing the dependencies.

Comment: My god! You saved me.

Answer (score 13):

if you use npm:

```
npm install  @emotion/react
```

if you use yarn:

```
yarn add @emotion/react
```

but in recent version they rename the package @emotion/core to @emotion/react, if you use other package that are depending on @emotion/core

- > that mean you need to hook up to source code and update import statement to the new @emotion/react

or downgrade package to older versions with npm

```
npm install @emotion/core@10.1.1
```

with yarn

```
yarn add @emotion/core@10.1.1
```

Answer (score 8):

**YOU NEED INSTALL : @emotion/react AND @emotion/styled WHILE @mui/material is installed**
and sometimes it look likes that it've finished but still no proggress, at these cases just w8 and it will finish depend on your connection speed

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

or

```
npm install @mui/material 
npm install @emotion/react 
npm install @emotion/styled
```

visit this for installation docs  [Installation MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/)

Answer (score 5):

None of these solutions worked for me. I resolved it by running:

```
npm install @emotion/server
```

I am using mui with nextjs.

Answer (score 2):

'yarn install' or 'node install' at the directory of package.json.

I'm looking at the docs, the package you're trying to use may not exist.

Make sure you are importing from the current library. For example:

```
import { NeuButton } from "neumorphism-react";
```

Answer (score 2):

using:

```
npm install @emotion/styled --force
npm install @emotion/react --force
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Only this worked for me:

```
npm i @emotion/styled @emotion/core
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below commands into package.json under Dependencies

```
"@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
```

Run npm install

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I tried `npm install @emotion/react` but it didn't solve my problem because I already had the package installed.

I restarted VS Code and the linter was happy

Comment: went through the exact same thing. Spent a good chunk of time trying to figure out what was going wrong, and it turned out a simple restart did the trick! 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and resolved it by running the below commands.

```bash
npm install @emotion/react
npm install @emotion/core
npm install @emotion/styled
```

These commands will install the emotion package to the dependencies of your project.

after this, make sure you restart your development server and your IDE if necessary. Your dev server won't pick up the changes until you stop it and re-run the npm start command.

also, install the `@emotion/css` package if you are using CSS as well.

If the error is still there then, try to delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file (**not package.json**) files, re-run `npm install`, and restart your IDE.

**visit for more information:** https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-module-not-found-cant-resolve-emotion-react

Answer (score 1):

TLDR for those who are using `nextJS`-

1. Rerun `npm run dev` to allow `nextJS` to rebuild the needed files.
2. Delete the `.next` folder like @FusionDevelopers suggested.

Explanation- when you run dev next builds a lot of the stuff to be served so when you're installing new libraries they won't necessarily be included in that build meaning your project will shout that it misses the things you already installed.
One option, as @FusionDevelopers suggested is to delete the `.next` folder, another option is to restart the `nextjs` server that'll rebuild everything including the newly installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

And after installing don't forget to restart your localhost, npm start

Answer (score 0):

I had all of the above and still was getting the error. I ended up deleting the yarn.lock & node_modules and the run `yarn` again

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the package definitions from **package.json** before running

```
npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Until I did that, it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Execute these two instructions:

I add this statement:

```
 npm install @emotion/styled
```

then i add this statement:

```
 npm update @emotion/styled
```

**With the previous two steps, the problem was solved in my code.**

If the problem isn't resolved, you can perform the next step:

```
npm install -g @emotion/styled
```