# Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in node_modules\@emotion\styled\base\dist'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, emotion-js

I tried the `npm install @emotion/react` and `npm install @emotion/styled` solutions and the error is not cleared.

Kindly help

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486256/module-not-found-cant-resolve-emotion-react)

Comment: Emotion/styled was installed correctly, but you're gonna have to retry with this command : npm install --save @emotion/react

Comment: Please share a bit more context. What's actually not working and where do you see the error

Answer (score 1):

After installing npm install @emotion/styled @emotion/core @emotion/react --save. Then Terminate the running Server and **restart** npm start.It worked for me.... this may work for you too.

Answer (score -1):

you have not installed npm packages correctly,
so, try to install them again using this command, those are missing from package.json, not installed properly

```
npm install @emotion/styled 
npm install @emotion/core
npm install @emotion/styled
```

or try installing them with `--save` flag

this is also worked for my friend,

```
yarn add @emotion/react @emotion/styled styled-components @emotion/core
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: /node_modules/@emotion/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.browser.esm.js

Comment: can you try to delete `node_modules` and do it again, else any one dependency surely missed in the `package.json` file, ask for seniors to share there `node_modules` zipped and replace yours folder then `npm i`

Comment: `$ yarn add @emotion/react @emotion/styled styled-components @emotion/core` I used this and it worked You can try this

Comment: The latter command is going to install both emotion and a competing CSS-in-JS library, `styled-components`.