# MUI Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react'

Tags: javascript, npm, material-ui

[Tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486256/module-not-found-cant-resolve-emotion-react), doesn't work

Using latest MUI

`Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react'`

Ok install it then..
`npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled -s`

Package showing up in `package-lock.json`.

```
"node_modules/@emotion/react": {
      "version": "11.7.1",
      ........
```

**Should be good to go..**

---

Start up the server..
`npm start`

**Once again..**
`Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react'`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
npm install @emotion/react
```

or

```
npm install @emotion/react 
npm install @emotion/styled
```

Comment: They're installed already as I detailed in my question